# Replace characters by matching string using several options

Tags: r, string, replace

I am trying to replace the parts of string by several matching expressions. I have found how to apply the `str_replace_all` on the specific column. But I do not know how to apply it within the dataframe with the `dplyr` piping?

Dummy example:

```
d <- data.frame(nam = c('aaa_string', 'bb_salala', 'cc_bububub'))

# applied on the d$nam vector every thing is working
d$nam %>% 
     str_replace_all(c("aaa" = "1", "bb" = "2", "cc" = "33"))
```

Using the same statement within the `mutate` it suddenly does not work, claiming that  `argument "pattern" is missing` in `str_replace_all`. How to fix it?

Expected output:

```
nam
"1_string"   
"2_salala"   
"33_bububub"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not clear about how the `mutate` statement was used.  The following works well.  In addition, if the `mutate` was masked by `plyr::mutate`, specify `dplyr::mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
d <- d %>%
   dplyr::mutate(nam = str_replace_all(nam, 
  c("aaa" = "1", "bb" = "2", "cc" = "33")))
```

-output

```
     nam
1   1_string
2   2_salala
3 33_bububub
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

d %>% 
  separate(nam, c("a", "b")) %>% 
  mutate(a = case_when(a == "aaa" ~ "1",
                       a == "bb" ~ "2",
                       a == "cc" ~ "33", 
                       TRUE ~ NA_character_)) %>% 
  mutate(nam = paste(a,b, sep = "_"), .keep="unused")
```

```
        nam
1   1_string
2   2_salala
3 33_bububub
```